# Node.js/Discord.js/Mongodb Need help pulling information using keywords

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord.js

I'm trying to pull information from a mongodb and send to a discord chat. For now, I'm trying to pull information from the DB and just send to console and then close the program. I can't seem to figure out how to pull the information from all the documents. It needs to search all the documents for specific keywords. Here is the code that I have:

```
const database = 'pidpid';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, user){
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");

    var db = user.db(database);
    db.collection("ingest").findOne({}, function(err,result){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(result.url);
        user.close();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create an index with the fields on the collection you want to use.

[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)

Next, you will be able to use $text follow by $search

```
.findOne({$text:{$search: <regex or text here>}}
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/